# Integral inequality $\int_{0}^{e}\operatorname{W(x)^{\pi}}>1$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, pi, lambert-w

Hi it's a problem of mine :

> > Prove that (without calculating the [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22rangestart%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22integral%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22W%28x%29%5Epi%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22rangeend%22%7D%20-%3E%22e%22)) :
> >     $$\int_{0}^{e}\operatorname{W(x)^{\pi}}\mathrm{d}x>1$$
> >     Where $\operatorname{W(x)}$ denotes the [Lambert's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) .

I have tested during 2 hours some methods but it fails always because the inequality is pretty sharp .Particulary I have used the power series of the Lambert's function but it's not convincing . So I really need help on this question .

If you have nice ideas...

...Thanks a lot.

Comment: $W(0)=0$ and $W(e)=1$, if you could show it is superlinear (compared to function $x/e$) in the region $x\in[0,e]$ then compare to a right angled triangle of side $e$ by height $1$, then area is greater than $1$, so the power of Pi doesn't matter? Just an idea... Might have made a mistake:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BProductLog%5Bx%5D%2Cx%2FE%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CE%7D%5D

Comment: Wolfy says it's about 1.0002, so it is surprisingly close.

Comment: @martycohen "Wolfy" 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach where we don't have to integrate the Lamberts function, but only one standard integral of the form $\int_0^1 x^n \exp(x) \text{d}x$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which can be solved explicitly using partial integration.

Let $g(x) = W^{-1}(x) = x \exp(x)$, then your integral becomes after a change of coordinates
\begin{align*}
\int_0^e W(x)^\pi \text{d}x &= \int_0^1 W(g(x))^\pi g'(x) \text{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 x^\pi\left(\exp(x) + x \exp(x) \right) \text{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 x^{\pi} \exp(x) \text{d}x  +  \int_0^1 x^{\pi + 1} \exp(x) \text{d}x.
\end{align*}
We can use partial integration for the first integral to obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_0^e W(x)^\pi \text{d}x &= \frac{1}{\pi+1} x^{\pi+1} \exp(x)\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=1} - \frac{1}{\pi+1} \int_0^1 x^{\pi+1} \exp(x) \text{d}x + \int_0^1 x^{\pi + 1} \exp(x) \text{d}x  \\
&= \frac{e}{\pi+1} + \frac{\pi}{\pi+1} \int_0^1 x^{\pi+1} \exp(x) \text{d}x.
\end{align*}
We apply another round of partial integration to find
\begin{align*}
\int_0^e W(x)^\pi \text{d}x &= \frac{e}{\pi+1} + \frac{e \pi}{(\pi+1)(\pi+2)} - \frac{\pi}{(\pi+1)(pi + 2)} \int_0^1 x^{\pi+2} \exp(x) \text{d}x.
\end{align*}
We can now bound the last integral from below by $- \int_0^1 x^5 \exp(x)\text{d}x$ as $x^5 > x^{\pi+2}$ on the interval $[0,1]$ to obtain $\int_0^e W(x)^\pi \text{d}x \ge 0.999$, hence we apply two extra rounds of partial integration to obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_0^e W(x)^\pi \text{d}x &= \frac{e}{\pi+1} + \frac{e \pi}{(\pi+1)(\pi+2)} - \frac{e\pi}{(\pi+1)(pi + 2)(\pi+3)} + \frac{e\pi}{((\pi+1)(pi + 2)(\pi+3)(\pi+4))} - \frac{\pi}{((\pi+1)(pi + 2)(\pi+3)(\pi+4))} \int_0^1 x^{\pi+4} \exp(x) \text{d}x.
\end{align*}
We now bound the integral from below by $- \int_0^1 x^7 \exp(x)\text{d}x$, to obtain $\int_0^e W(x)^\pi \text{d}x \ge 1.00018$.

Furthermore, we could keep applying integration by parts to find the integral of $\int_0^e W(x)^\pi \text{d}x$ as 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^e W(x)^\pi \text{d}x &= \frac{e}{\pi+1} + e \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\pi}{\prod_{m=1}^n (\pi + m)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: (+1) It is a nice solution.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you :). It is just a shame it still needs 4 rounds of partial integration.

Comment: Your first step is enough which makes an integration of elementary function.

Comment: let me the time to analyze this .First what is partial integration ? Furthermore in the last product it is not $n$ instead of $m$?Anyway thank you !

Comment: Oh for partial integration I have found a link so let me understand...You have a problem of typo with $\pi$ instead of $pi$

Comment: Oh i see we just have to differentiate with respect to $x$ to get the integral no?

Comment: Partial integration says $\int_a^b F g = F(b)G(b) - F(a)G(a) - \inf_a^b f G$ when $F' = f$ and $G' = g$.

Answer (score 1):

*Not very rigorous.*

Use the Taylor series of $W(x)$ around $x=e$ up to order $O\left((x-e)^{n+1}\right)$, raise it to power $\pi$ to get things like
$$1+\frac{\pi  (x-e)}{2 e}+\frac{\pi  (2 \pi -5) (x-e)^2}{16 e^2}+\frac{\pi 
   \left(45-30 \pi +4 \pi ^2\right) (x-e)^3}{192 e^3}+\frac{\pi  (-583+510 \pi -120 \pi ^2+8 \pi ^3) (x-e)^4}{3072 e^4}+O\left((x-e)^5\right)$$ Integrate termwise between the bounds to get $\big[e\times P_n(\pi)\big]$

Below are given the decimal representation of the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \text{result} \\
 1 & 0.58334827279065 \\
 2 & 0.81164122032718 \\
 3 & 0.92027110969382 \\
 4 & 0.96636673732565 \\
 5 & 0.98665793725515  \\
 6 & 0.99583123255972  \\
 7 & 0.99996493384791  \\
 8 & 1.00173198491504 \\
 9 & 1.00236972369043 \\
 10 & 1.00247298096855 \\
 11 & 1.00233463559724 \\
 12 & 1.00210020862900 \\
 13 & 1.00184132446202 \\
 14 & 1.00159192031259 \\
 15 & 1.00136660705921 \\
 16 & 1.00117017261118 \\
 17 & 1.00100256311893 \\
 18 & 1.00086150355766 \\
 19 & 1.00074386588970 \\
 20 & 1.00064636610536
\end{array}
\right)$$